# Which client can run in Java 1.6 & query from Elasticsearch 5.4?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, web-applications, java-6, elasticsearch-5

I'm currently using Elasticsearch 1.7.3 and I wanna upgrade to Elasticsearch 5.4. As per my understanding Elasticsearch 5.4 runs on Java 1.8. my application is running in Java6, and I'm using Jest 0.1.5 client for ES queries. I'd like to understand if I can still use Jest 0.1.5 that runs in Java 1.6 and query from Elasticsearch 5.4. If not, do suggest any alternate approach or client that can run on Java6 but can query from Elasticsearch 5.4. Thanks in advance﻿

Comment: Not going to answer as I don't have the exact answer at hand but Java 6 AND Java 7 are already too old. Definitely upgrade your application JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can still use Jest but submit queries in [plain JSON](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest#searching-documents). At this point though it does not make difference if to make queries with a plain HTTP client or with Jest.

As Elastic says in their [blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/state-of-the-official-elasticsearch-java-clients):

> The Java REST client is the future for Java users of Elasticsearch. Please get involved and try out the high-level client as soon as it becomes available

[Java REST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html) client requires Java 1.7.